# How to compare 2 times with PHP

Tags: php

I got arrays of time from DB. And want to compare which one is newer than current.

$data[]=array();

`00:05, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 00:50, 01:00, ... 23:25, 23:30, 23:45`

Then I reformat to `Y-m-d H:i` so I can compare with `strtotime()`

```
$timenow=date("Y-m-d H:i");

foreach($data as $key=>$val){
  $time=date("Y-m-d")." ".$val;
  echo $time." >= ".$timenow." ".var_dump(strtotime($time)>=strtotime($timenow))."<hr />";
}
```

But all I got is `false`

```
bool(false) 2021-07-14 00:05 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 00:15 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 00:30 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 00:45 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 00:50 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
.
.
.
bool(false) 2021-07-14 23:25 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 23:30 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
bool(false) 2021-07-14 23:45 >= 2021-07-14 19:35
```

Please help me, where did I miss?

Comment: Why are you involving the date at all? Just format the current time as `HH:mm` as well, then you can do simple _string comparison_.

Comment: Because it's not working. No matter how I compare it. Then I assume that it must have smth to do with format? Any idea?

Comment: Even I compare with pure time format. It turns all false as well.

`bool(false) 18:30 >= 19:48
bool(false) 18:45 >= 19:48
bool(false) 19:00 >= 19:48
bool(false) 19:10 >= 19:48
bool(false) 19:15 >= 19:48
bool(false) 19:30 >= 19:48
bool(false) 19:45 >= 19:48
bool(false) 20:00 >= 19:48`

Comment: The code as given works as expected here; I'd use a debugger and inspect the data closely, something is not what you assume.

Comment: No idea what you are even talking about, the code as shown appears to work fine already: https://3v4l.org/W2Jgu

Comment: You could just concat the current date on the time and append seconds, then compare in DB with `now()`

Comment: It gives me all falses. Is there anything to do with timezone?

Comment: Try converting your times to DateTime objects and then comparing them.

Comment: Check the space in the `$time` concatenation - if it is an unbreakable space, `strtotime` will return `false`

Comment: Isn't it needs a space between them?

Comment: yes a space, but not an unbreakable space - different characters (depending on the encoding,  space is 0x20, nbrk-spc 0xa0) -- just an idea, the behaviour I see changes to what you observe if I make that change;

Comment: OK, guys! If got an answer. Because time from `db` is `H:i:s`. But I compare with `H:i`. So now it's done! Thank you every answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot I do not like about your code but lets take a closer look I assume your $data variable is something like that:

```
$data = array('time0' => '2021-07-14 23:45', 
              'time1' => '2021-07-14 00:15', 
              'time2' => '2021-07-14 00:30', 
              'time3' => '2021-07-14 00:45');
```

The only thing that we need from the pairs is the values in this particular case e.g. '2021-07-14 23:45'.
So we convert them in timestamp `strtotime($val)` and `strtotime($timenow)`
We assign result from the comparison to variable `$bool` (**BAD PRACTISE**. It's just for visualising the correct results)

```
$timenow=date("Y-m-d H:i");

foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $bool = strtotime($val) >= strtotime($timenow);
    var_dump($bool ,$val , $timenow);
}
```

var_dump displays structured information about type and value of our variables. The results are:

```
bool(true)
string(16) "2021-07-14 23:45"
string(16) "2021-07-14 13:23"
bool(false)
string(16) "2021-07-14 00:15"
string(16) "2021-07-14 13:23"
bool(false)
string(16) "2021-07-14 00:30"
string(16) "2021-07-14 13:23"
bool(false)
string(16) "2021-07-14 00:45"
string(16) "2021-07-14 13:23"
```